# dbi gives undef as if empty but the query yields result in mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a mysql-query that yields only one row and column, when checking the query interactively I can see the result, which is what I want. But when I use 
`$sth->fetchrow_hashref;`
I get undef.
Does anyone have any idea of what might be wrong here?
I am thankful for any point in any direction.y produces your result.

This is done directly after the execute:

```
sub _get_next_hashref
{
    my $self = shift;
    if($self->{sth} ne '') {
    if(my $hash_ref = $self->{sth}->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        return $hash_ref;
    } else {
        $self->{sth} = '';
        return undef;
        }
    } else {
    return undef;
    }    
}
```

Some additional information:

The query executed ends with `limit 1`, so there should only be one row at all times. For some reason in-data that otherwise would result in more rows work perfectly, but in-data that only produces one-row-results does not work.

```
$sql = "select sort_order from forum.metatag_sort where metatag=? order by id desc limit 1";
$self->{sth} = $self->{dbh}->prepare($sql);
if($self->{sth}->execute(@args)) {
    return _get_next_hashref();
}
```

Within @args is only the metatag, an int.

Cases where
    `select count(sort_order) from forum.metatag_sort where metatag=?`
would return an answer greater than 1 works flawlessly for me, but cases where this would return exactly 1 fails.

Comment: Please show the full piece of code that actually produces your result. We're usually not clairvoyant.

Comment: Show us the query, and how you execute it.

Comment: And now show us the code that actually calls your `_get_next_hashref` function. Additionally there's no need to compare `$self->{sth}` with `ne`. Simply do `if ($self->{sth})` which will yield true if `$self->{sth}` exists, is defined and generally trueish for Perl. Meaning if there's a statement handle stored then it will be true. An empty string is falsish.

Answer (score 1):

Your `_get_next_hashref`-definition looks like method for some class, but you calling it like function:

```
if($self->{sth}->execute(@args)) {
    return _get_next_hashref();
}
```

So it gets no object information and it can't return anything but `undef`.

Comment: `_get_next_hashref` works fine for most cases I assure you. It returns a hashref for the working scenario I described.

Comment: @user1808687: and those other cases you call it also functional way? Certainly not like `$my_object->_get_next_hashref`? How then `my $self = shift;` could work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've forgotten to set `$sql` to the SQL string:

> ```
> "select sort_order from forum.metatag_sort where metatag=? order by id desc limit 1"
> $self->{sth} = $self->{dbh}->prepare($sql);
> ```

Are you using `strict` and `warnings`? Consider this:following:

```
"some code";
print "bar";
```

`use warnings` should tell you the this line:

> Useless use of a constant (some code) in void context at scratch.pl line 5318.

---

I took the liberty of altering the code a bit for you.

- As @MoritzBunkus said, you don't need to compare `$self->{sth}` to anything. If there's a statement handle in it, it will be true. If not, it will be false.
- Don't put a `return` in an `else` block if there is a `return` in the 'then'-block. You don't need the `else`. Just put it below the `if`-statement.
- `return` without an argument always returns `undef`. See [ProhibitExplicitReturnUndef](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/ProhibitExplicitReturnUndef.pm).

Here's how I'd do it:

```
sub _get_next_hashref {
  my ($self) = @_;
  if ($self->{sth}) {
    if(my $hash_ref = $self->{sth}->fetchrow_hashref) {
      return $hash_ref;
    }
    # this will only be called if there was no result, thus no else needed
    undef $self->{sth}; # set to undef (or = '') if you must
  }
  # see above
  return; # returns undef if no param is given
}
```

Comment: The variable $sql is set in another place, but to the exact string I posted. It shortens down the code, and perhaps increase readability, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, `fetchrow_hashref` still returns undef where it should return an answer.